# Reading a 10 digit Integer from sqlite to C++ program

Tags: sqlite, long-integer

I am trying to read a 10-12 digit signed integer value stored in a sqlite database. I want to read it into an int variable in my c++ code. I am trying the following query but I know I am going wrong somewhere as the value I retrieve from the database is always a negative number, different from the one in the database.

```
"SELECT _id FROM Picture where Time<%lld"
```

I am then appending the integer value to the above string, before sending it to sqlite, by using sprintf. When I print out the query, it shows a neg. long int number. What am I doing wrong with the query?

Thanks,

Ab

Comment: What is the datatype of the database field? What is the number that you're having trouble reading?

Comment: How's your integer defined in SQLite and in C? If sqlite's unsigned, and C's signed, then anything over the /2 halfway point is going to show up as negative in the other system.

Comment: actually, I just figured out that the query that I am constructing before sending it to sqlite itself is not right. Before sending the above query to sqlite, I send another query "SELECT Time FROM Picture WHERE _id=%d" where %d is the ID of the other INTEGER data I am trying to retrieve. For e.g. the ID is 500, so the above query is "SELECT Time FROM Picture WHERE _id=500". When this is sent  to sqlite, I should get the long int number back. In my C++ code, I retrieve it in Time = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0); where Time is defined as a signed long long.

Comment: is this correct?                         signed long long Time; Time = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0); //where stmt is constructed out of my query - "SELECT Time FROM Picture WHERE _id=%d"? also, the table 'Picture' has an INTEGER type field called 'Time' which is what I am trying to retrieve

Comment: I figured out where I was going wrong. The field I was trying to read holds 64-bit integer type and I was using sqlite3_column_int instead of sqlite3_column_int64. I changed it to the latter and got the data back in my c++ signed long long variable.

Thanks for giving me little bit of direction there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where I was going wrong. The field I was trying to read holds 64-bit integer type and I was using sqlite3_column_int instead of sqlite3_column_int64. I changed it to the latter and got the data back in my c++ signed long long variable.

Thanks for giving me little bit of direction there.